# Incorrect email textbox layout format

Tags: email, formatting, long-text-area

When sending an email from within a case (or other object records) in Salesforce, after accidentally pressing a specific key combination, I am now unable to use the full text box pane, instead I am limited to a small portion of it. How do I reset the text box so that I can use the full extent of the box. 
[image]

Inspect Element[image]

Comment: Looks like the width of your iframe got decreased somehow. I don't know how that could have happened with a key combination. Does it happen every time you go to this screen? Or was it a one-off thing?

Comment: thanks @guy it happens every time now, 'very limiting...

Comment: which browser is this? And what do you see when you right-click the textbox and click an option like 'inspect element' (exact name is browser-dependant)

Comment: Chrome V33.0.1...I will attached screenshot of "inspect element" to question.

Comment: furthermore, it doesn't happen in IE (V8.0.76)

Comment: I'm puzzled.. I can't imagine this coming from a keyboard combo. Could there be any javascript running on the page? Furthermore, the actual tag that is probably wrong is just a bit higher in your html markup. Do you have this line (about  lines higher)? <table id="single" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  If I change that width, I get the same symptoms as you have (but only on the current page, not anymore after a reload).